# "Package does not exist" error using Android v4 Compatibility Library

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm using MonoDroid 4.2 in Visual Studio 2010, and I'm trying to use ViewPager, Fragments, and other things from the Android v4 Compatibility Library.

I was able to add the project reference to `Mono.Android.Support.v4.dll` and at design time I get no errors and intellisense works fine.

But when I build, I get errors like this:

> package android.support.v4.view.ViewPager does not exist
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener

If I double-click on the error, it opens the source java file that MonoDroid creates on the fly, and goes to the line with the problem:

```
public class ViewPagerTestActivity_MyPagerAdapter
  extends android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter
```

So it looks like Java can't find the library package, but I'm not sure why.  Do I need to install that manually, and how do I tell MonoDroid where to find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, I learned that I needed to actually **install** the support library.  MonoDroid has .NET bindings for it, but the underlying java can't build without it, of course.  Here are [instructions for getting the support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) and [instructions for hooking it up to a MonoDroid project](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Platform_Features/Fragments/Fragments_Walkthrough/Part_2_-_Supporting_pre-Honeycomb_Android_using_Support_Packages).

Comment: See also http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Platform_Features/Fragments/Part_4_-_Providing_Backwards_Compatibility_with_the_Android_Support_Package#Adding_The_V4_Libraries_to_a_Mono_for_Android_Project