# Xamarin Android Support V4 error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-support-library

I started a new default working project in xamarin and I added the dll references for Xamarin.Android.Support.V4 and  Xamarin.Android.Support.V7.AppCompat and I am getting errors.

```
Error: package android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager does not exist
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener

Error: package android.support.v4.content.Loader does not exist
android.support.v4.content.Loader.OnLoadCompleteListener

...
```

[image]
What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed to actually install the support library. MonoDroid has .NET bindings for it, but the underlying java can't build without it, of course. Here are [instructions for getting the support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) and [instructions for hooking it up to a MonoDroid project](http://developer.xamarin.com/Guides/Android/Platform_Features/Fragments/Fragments_Walkthrough/Part_2_-_Supporting_pre-Honeycomb_Android_using_Support_Packages/).

See also http://developer.xamarin.com/Guides/Android/Platform_Features/Fragments/Part_4_-_Providing_Backwards_Compatibility_with_the_Android_Support_Package/#Adding_The_V4_Libraries_to_a_Mono_for_Android_Project

This might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update/16610247#16610247) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update/16608570#16608570), which were solutions to common problems in the rev. 22 update.

Comment: You can specify more accurate solution instead of refering to other links

Comment: @Endri: When you take an answer AS IS from another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361613/package-does-not-exist-error-using-android-v4-compatibility-library) you should give credit and not pass it as your own.

Answer (score -1):

try calling it with this:

```
using Android.Support.V4;
```

Comment: you have install them from nuget packages? try install them from components

Answer (score -1):

I was reading another post in the xamarin forms with the same issue and this worked for me. I spent maybe an hour trying to figure out what to do and the guy I ran into said just to:

clean the solution, 
rebuild it,
then it should be fixed.

Assuming the packages are still installed

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17579407)

Comment: @Vorsprung why do you think that this does not answer the question? _"clean the solution, rebuild it, then it should be fixes"_. It is maybe bad explained and a bit cluttered (the first sentence is useless), but it clearly indicates a solution, so I think this _is_ a perfectly legit answer.

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus  please see the community guidelines for answers  here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .  In particular, "do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better"  Hope this helps

Comment: @Vorsprung if an answer gives a solution, even if partial, not explained, badly formatted, or too brief, it remains an _answer_. A very poor one, but in this case you can simply downvote it. The flag "not-an-answer" applies in cases where the answer doesn't try to give a solution _at all_, deviating from the question, or giving just lateral thoughts, or trying to answer to other answers, or writing useless things or spam. See [this discussion on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag/185074#185074).

Comment: I don't agree with your analysis.  We'll have to differ in our opinion

Comment: Well to settle this because it seemed to have ended sour, I didn't answer the question: "What did I do wrong?"
So Vorsprung isn't wrong.


However, what I fail to understand is the purpose of arguing such a position when the purpose of asking "what's wrong?" is an underlying search for a solution.